# Algorithm to decrypt data with drawn strokes

Tags: algorithm, encryption, drawing

Let's say I have an encrypted file on an iPhone and every time I want to decrypt it, I want to "draw" a decryption symbol instead of having to use a keyboard to type it in.

If you request from the user to draw a symbol to decrypt a file every time it is needed (e.g. every time they launch your application) they would probably prefer it to having to type a 20 character or so password on the tiny keyboard, and they would still get the security a 20 character password would give them (depending on how complicated the shape/symbol they draw is).

The symbol they would draw would most likely be one stroke (e.g. it's over once you lift up your finger) but can be very complex, such that it's hard for someone else to repeat it, even if they do see you draw it in. Kind of like how every person's signature is unique and hard to duplicate. Actually, this may just overly complicate it if it had to prevent from being duplicated, so for now this can be ignored and we can assume that the symbol will not be seen by someone else and thus it doesn't matter if it could be repeated by them or not.

I guess the real question is how would you convert the same (reasonably) stroke consistently to the same key (e.g. hash value). There should obviously be some threshold of forgiveness in the algorithm, because the user can't be expected to repeat the stroke exactly 100%.

Using the symbol as a decryption method adds a whole other dimension to this problem. You never want to store the generated hash value anywhere in unencrypted form, cause then someone might be able to access that part of the hard drive and get the decryption key without needing to go through the whole drawing process and decrypt the file manually. You also most likely don't want to store anything about how the shape is drawn.

A good example of a stroke that a user might use as their decryption symbol is the "&" symbol. Imagine a user drawing this symbol on their iPhone every time they need to decrypt a file. The size of the symbol might not be the same every time it is drawn. Also, the rotation of the symbol may be different depending on how the user holds their device. Ideally, in both cases, because the symbol was drawn, relative to the user strokes, the same, it should be able to generate the same hash value and thus decrypt the file.

I thought something like shape or character recognition is a similar algorithm. Where the user draws something (reasonably representing a shape) and it then fixes it to the correct shape which would have the same hash value every time it is drawn. However, for something like this you would most likely need a database of shapes that can be drawn, and if you choose something like all the letters in the alphabet, you only get 26 letters. And assuming the user should only need to draw one symbol to decrypt the file, you have an extremely insecure password with only 26 possibilities.

Another thing I thought of is you could break up the symbol that is drawn into tiny segments and then run symbol recognition on those. So imagine that you have 4 symbols in a database: vertical line, horizontal line, and diagonal in both directions. Now as the user draws, each segment is recognized as one of these, and then they are all combined to form some hash value. So imagine the user chose as their decryption symbol the lowercase letter "r". So they would begin by drawing a vertical line down, followed by a vertical line up, followed by a diagonal line up and to the right. One problem with this method is how would you know when to split up the stroke into individual segments? You would probably also want to take into account how long each individual segment is roughly (e.g. in increments of 40 pixels). That way if someone drew a deformed "r" where the hump comes out near the bottom it isn't recognized as the same symbol and thus wouldn't decrypt the file.

A third method might be dividing the screen up into a grid (not sure which size yet) and simply seeing in which cells the stroke is drawn and using this data somehow to generate a string.

Any other ideas of how this could be implemented? Have you ever heard of something like this? Are there any fundamental flaws that would prevent a system like this from working?

Thanks

Comment: Interesting problem and a thorough treatment.  Kudos.  Unfortunately I don't see any way to get around the fidelity problem without a fixed symbol database (such as OCR software uses), which as you point out would not be secure enough for serious work.

Comment: You may be interested in this LaTeX symbol recogniser; it's pretty cool: http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html

Comment: Interesting problem. What if you tried constraining it some -- convert a small, easy-to-recognize set of symbols into a few bits of the encryption key? If you can get a full byte of key data from a single symbol, that's better than ascii. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem of encrypting data with keymaterial that may have small errors has been studied quite extensively.
In particular there are a number of proposals for protecting data using biometric data (e.g. fingerprints or a retina scan) as a key. A typical approach is to use an appropriate error correction code, take your original key material K, compute the syndrome of it and only store the syndrome. Once you get a second reading of your key material K', the syndrome can be use to restore K from K' if K and K' are close enough (where 'close enough" of course depends on the error correction scheme.)

To get you started, here is a paper proposing a [fuzzy vault scheme](http://www.rsa.com/rsalabs/staff/bios/ajuels/publications/fuzzy-vault/fuzzy_vault.pdf). This is a general proposal for an encryption scheme using a "fuzzy" key. Of course, you still need to examine how to extract characteristics from drawings that are stable enough for using such an error correction scheme. You will also have to examine how much entropy you can extract from such drawings. As bad as passwords are with respect to entropy, they may still be hard to beat.

Comment: The problem of converting a biological fingerprint into a reproducible cryptographic key seems like it would have a lot in common with this idea - so I'd agree with this answer and go have a read of the academic papers exploring that.

Answer (score 3):

I would try a variation of the segmentation variant: Recognize simple patterns - I'll stick to straight and diagonal lines for this, but in theory you could also add circles, arcs and perhaps other things.

You can be quite sure when one line ends and another one starts as there are 8 directions and you can detect a direction change (or for a simpler approach, just detect pen up and pen down and use them as line delimiters). The first line gives a scale factor, so the length of every other line can be represented as a factor (for example, in an usual L shape, the first vertical line would give the "base length" b and the other line would then have the length of roughly 0.5 * b). After the user is finished, you can use the smallest factor s to "round" the lengths, so that you'll have an array of integer lengths like [1 * s, 2 * s, 4 * s, 5 * s]. This will prevent the system from being too exact, and using the base length makes the system robust against scaling.

Now somehow convert these informations (lengths and directions) to a string (or a hash value, whatever you like) and it will be the same for the same strokes, even if the symbol is translated or scaled.

Additionally, you can store an 2D offset value (of course "rounded", too) for every line after the second line so that the lines will also have to be at the same position, if you don't do this, L and T will most likely get the same string (1 line up-down, 1 line left-right length 0.5). So storing positions strengthens the whole thing a bit but is optional.

EDIT:

If you take the angle of the first line as a base angle, you can even make this robust to rotation.

Please note that this algorithm only gives 3 bits per stroke if all lines are of the same length and a maximum of perhaps up to 6-8 bits per stroke, some more if you store positions, too. This means you'd need a quite complex symbol of about 20-40 strokes to get 128 bits of security.

An easy way to add more variation/security would be to let the user use different colors from a given palette.

To reduce the risk of someone watching you, you could make each line disappear after it has been drawn or change the color to a color with a very low contrast to the background.

Comment: Nice method of allowing the symbol to be drawn in different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Handwriting recognition often takes the *duration* of the stroke into account more than the actual length and such.

While it relates to pressure sensitivity, I think you may be able to see some similar conceptual bits to what you are thinking here.... [jdadesign.net/safelock/](http://jdadesign.net/safelock/)

That's not exactly the same topic, but it's the closest thing that comes to mind at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that you could get enough "bits" from a hand-drawn symbol to perform secure encryption. As you note, you have to allow enough slop in the recognition that the natural variations in drawing will be tolerated. In other words, you have to discard noise in the strokes, smoothing them into reproducible signal. But noise (high entropy) makes better cryptographic keys.

Think of it this way. If you did decompose the gesture into segments of up, down, left, and right, each segment would represent 2 bits of information. For an AES key, the symbol would need 64 such segments. That's a pretty complicated gesture to remember. And if it's simplified by repeating many segments in a row ("right, right, right, ...") it makes a lousy (predictable, non-random) key.

Comment: +1 for calling attention to the low entropy problem, although it is still possible to get enough bits by careful choosing the algorithm (Although this doesn't really prevent users to choose too easy symbols, but that's about the same thing as with weak passwords)

Answer (score 1):

I've had another think about this. I'm not a comp-sci person, but would something like this work.

Let's say that with whatever symbol or "pattern" someone draws. The only viable thing you're left with to analyze are all the points in the pattern generated in touchBegan, touchMoved and touchEnded events.

So... let's take all the points generated, be it 100 or 1,000,000, it doesn't really matter.

Divide them into groups, as many groups as you want. The more the merrier I assume, but for this example, let's put them in 4 groups. With 100 points, group 1 would contain points 1 > 25, group 2 contains 26 > 50 and so on.

For each group, use all the points to calculate an average position.

It may work better if the canvas spaces is divided into a grid, and the 'average positions' get plotted onto their nearest coordinate.

Then check the relative distance between all the groups. So the between 1,2 1,3 1,4 2,3 2,4 3,4.

You now have as many distinct points, and information about those points to generate a key. The averages and the grid should help smooth out some, if not all of the entropy.

You may have to ask the user to draw their pattern a few times, and compare each group against groups from previous attempts. That way, you can identify which groups the users can plot consistently. It has the added benefit of training the users hand at drawing their pattern.

I suspect that the more points and groups you have, the more accurate this will be.

In fact, I'm going to give it a try myself.

Comment: Interesting implementation... I'd be interested in knowing if you could get it to work consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Gestures.

http://depts.washington.edu/aimgroup/proj/dollar/

You can define you own algorithms for particular gestures. EG a circle,

1.Find the start point
2. find the most left, most right and furthest for points and get an approximate radius.
3. check all the points against the radius with a margin of error (25%?)
4. If the radius checks out, you have a circle.

Vertical Straight line:
1. Check the start point and end point X and Y positions.
2. Compare the inbetween points against the x and y of the start and end.
3. If they're roughly on the same X coord, but ascending or descending Y coords, you have a vertical line.

And so on, getting more complex for more complicated gestures.

You can even combine gestures. So let's say you have an algorithm for 6 gestures. You can combine them to form different symbols. The order in which the gestures are created could be important, adding an extra layer of security.

Comment: That approach can only recognize symbols it's been told about in advance, though.  Even if you go really crazy and teach it to recognize a thousand symbols, that's still a tiny keyspace to explore for an attacker who knows what's in your symbol dictionary.

Comment: I don't think so. If you have 10 gestures, and each "key" is comprised of a minimum of 3 gestures, that's a key space of 1000. If you have 15 Gestures, and users can use all 15 gestures in their key, that's a keyspace of 1307674368000

Comment: Schnaader's suggestion of using color takes it up a level, and taking in the relative positioning would also help.

Comment: Although this is a valid way to do this, I don't like using predefined gestures. This way, you could also just show 15 buttons with the different gestures and a color palette and forget about the whole recognition thing. And you have to at least documentate the possible gestures to explain them to the user.

Answer (score 0):

what if you took all of the x,y coordinates of the stroke and preformed some sort of linear 2 way operation on them?  You could then compute an 'approximate' hash, and if the number calculated when the stroke is within... say 10% of your approximation, then you grant access..

Comment: You can't really grant access, since the only way to decrypt the file is by using this generated hash value. (e.g. imagine I'm using AES to encrypt the information). The decryption key is not stored anywhere as this would present a security risk. The only way for me to decrypt the data is with the generated hash value, thus, it must be exact.

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on what kind of attack you are trying to prevent against. If you want full on encryption, where you assume that the attacker has full access to the encrypted file, then you'll need quite a lot of bits of entropy to achieve a decent level of protection. Assuming you get the algorithms right, then you can take the two to the power of the entropy of input in bits (the upper limit for this is the number of different possible inputs), multiply by the amount of time the key setup procedure takes, divide by how much more computing power the attacker has and get the time the attacker has to take to break your encryption by brute force.

For example, something like the 9 cell figure unlock method of android might get you around 16 bits of entropy. Lets assume you use 5 seconds of CPU time to calculate the encryption key. Then with an average PC, it takes 5*2**16/20 seconds, or about 4.5 hours to crack. Any loss of entropy in the input or inefficiency in the key-setup and encryption will quickly take that down to minutes, not to mention if clusters of computers are used.

To be frank, that won't be much better than just storing the file in an obscure file format and hoping no one figures it out